# Assign products to parent category shopware 5

Tags: shopware

I'm trying to do something but without luck at the moment. I have a category, let say phones and inside another category as child, let say accessories. This is a easy structure to create, the problem is I can't assign any product to phones (it look like a folder), so I created a phones category inside phones:

phones
--phones
--accessories

This is working too but the url would be website/phones/phones and also this option appears twice in the menu. Is there any way to do this on shopware?

Answer (score 0):

In Shopware 5 you are limited to assign products to the lowest category of a category tree. So there is no option (without extending Shopware 5) to assign a product to parent category.